# Spring Config Server - SearchPath and repos

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to use Spring Config server and is trying to explore the 'repos'. Please see the configuration below where am trying to add a search folder under a dummy repository. When I add the search path on top ('folder1') it works just fine however when I add a search path for sample 2, it is not searching the path inside. What am I doing wrong here?. Any help is appreciated.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file://${user.home}/Documents/sample1
          default-label: main
          search-paths: folder1
          cloneOnStart: true
        repos:
         dummy:
            #pattern: dev*
            uri: file://${user.home}/Documents/sample2
            search-paths: folder2 // This not working
            default-label: main

        native:
          searchLocations: file://${user.home}/Documents/junk/

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Hey @Aravind R, did you find a solution to your problem?